# How do I replicate a website's JSON Request in my Android App

Tags: android, json, header, request, httpurlconnection

It is possible to replicate a JSON request from a website? For example, if I want to pull publicly available date from a website into my android application, can i use chrome's dev tools to lookup the way the website requests the data and replicate it?
Here is an example, I want to get an estimate of Moneygram transfer fees.
here is the way the request is structured on their site:
[Request Headers Screenshot from chrome dev tools 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSuub.png)

[Request Headers Screenshot from chrome dev tools 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk4Yp.png)

If it's possible to replicate that request from Android, how do i do it.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to replicate a JSON request from a website?

Yes, if you are authorised to access that data you can definitely make a similar request from your android application.

> can i use chrome's dev tools to lookup the way the website requests the data and replicate it?

Yes that is one of the way to see the request parameters, but I'll suggest you to refer the API documentation of the service provider. In that way you'll get all the necessary information about accessing the API (endpoints, parameters, headers, etc.).

> how do i do it.

This is a very broad question. There are millions of tutorials available on the internet which will help you in this task. Have a look at one of them to begin with. I'll suggest to refer the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) on the Android developers website.